# Redux saga yield put unit test not working

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, sinon, redux-saga

I looking to [doc](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing/) and some [samples](https://codeburst.io/how-i-test-redux-saga-fcc425cda018) online, but still not working. I use Sinon for unit test, and I keep getting this error, stuck on this one so long, can't figure it out.

> expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, combinator, ...) }

My action

```
export const loadingStatus = (response) => {
    return { type: "LOADING_STATUS", response };
};
```

My saga

```
export function* mySampleSaga() {
    try {
        yield put(loadingStatus('loading'));
        yield delay(1000);
        const config = yield select(getConfig);

        const requestCall = new SendingRequest(config);

        const linkRequests = yield select(getLinks);
        const response = yield call(
            [requestService, requestCall.sample],
            "2020-01-01",
            "2020-12-21"
        );
        const result = get(response, 'entities.requests', {});
        yield put(success(result));
        yield put(loadingStatus('done'));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(sendError(error));
        yield put(loadingStatus('done'));
    }
}
```

My test

```
describe('sample saga', () => {
    const config = {
        sample: "123"
    };

    const linkRequests = ['12345', '5678910'];

    it('should update request status - happy path', () => {
        const gen = mySampleSaga();
        expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put(loadingStatus('loading')));  // This keep getting error below

    });

    it('If saga has error', () => {
        const gen = mySampleSaga();
        const error = new Error('error');
        gen.next();
        expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put(sendError(error)));
        expect(gen.next().value).to.deep.equal(put(loadingStatus('done')));
        expect(gen.next().done).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you able to put a breakpoint in debugger and inspect the values? I suggest extracting two variables `const a = gen.next().value` and `const b = put(...)` and inspect `a` and `b`

Comment: Tried that, with the same error. Thank you